# RF Receiver for USB

Tags: usb, rf, remote

I wanted to make a wireless 6 or more channel remote controller for PC. The receiver connected to PC through USB or any interface possible in a modern laptop. More specifically I want an idea to design a wireless or wired game show lockout buzzer which can connect to a modern PC (no parallel or serial ports except USB).

I explored the a circuit at : http://electrosofts.com/parallel/buzzer.html
This connects to the parallel port. It would be great if we can interface it to USB.

I expect it to be possible by an RF receiver for PC and decoding the signal at PC.

If it is a wired solution, How can I interface it with PC through USB?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5):

[These](http://iteadstudio.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=7&products_id=53&zenid=qa08tp07o8bn54mjpo155e5o16) low-cost Nordic Semi nRF24L01+ transceiver modules interfaced to a suitable MCU (I'm using the PIC18F24J11) are ideal for the remote units. You can interface a push-button and piezo element to the MCU. You then need to interface one of the modules to a PC USB port using a suitable MCU, such as a PIC18F2455. Each unit can be built for about $10.

Comment: That seems to be a costly option for me ! I would look at a wired alternative too for this !

Comment: If $10 is costly, your options are severely limited.  $10 *is* low cost.

Comment: @KevinVermeer lol! This was back in college here in India. Yep! thankful to a bit more  prosperous now :)

Answer (score 2):

What country are you in?

Cheapest wired solution with a USB interface is probably a parallel port to USB converter. These are sold for as little as $US4 each (links at end).

For up to 8 channels (or even a few more with care) almost no other hardware is needed.

- Depending on the hardware in the adapter that you use you may not need the resistors shown here.
- Worst case you need one resistor per switch
- Depending on the adapter, you may find that the inputs are pulled high or low by default.
- If they are pulled low then you may be able to pull them high with a switch.
- If they are pulled high then you may be able to pull them low with a switch.
- If they are inconsistent (neither high or low reliably) then using resistors as shown will allow you to pull them to the other polarity with a switch.
- Note that in the diagram the resistor is shown going to v+ and the switch to ground, but these may be swapped if desired.

[image]

This diagram comes from the excellent tutorial referred to below.

Here is a [Parallel port switch input tutorial](http://www.ece.msstate.edu/~reese/ece3724/lectures/chap8_parport.pdf). This is for a traditional parallel port but much is applicable.

[Another tutorial. Not so useful, but shows connections](http://images.search.yahoo.com/images/view?back=http%3A%2F%2Fus.yhs4.search.yahoo.com%2Fyhs%2Fsearch%3Fei%3DUTF-8%26p%3Dswitch%2Binput%2B%2Bparallel%2Bport&w=620&h=305&imgurl=www.machinegrid.com%2Fmachinepress%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fmedia%2Fimages%2Fparallelin_files%2Fswitch.jpg&size=&name=switch+jpg%0A++++&rcurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.machinegrid.com%2F2008%2F12%2Fparallel-port-tutorial-part-2-handling-inputs&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.machinegrid.com%2F2008%2F12%2Fparallel-port-tutorial-part-2-handling-inputs&p=switch+input+parallel+port&type=jpeg&no=1&tt=22&oid=759c0aeedb56ba6e&tit=switch+jpg&sigr=12g6c964g&sigi=12s9s28c1&sigb=12hnu19dc&fr=altavista)

[Here are a few example images of the sort of device I mean](http://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?_adv_prop=image&fr=altavista&va=usb+to+parallel+port+adapter) using Yahoo search. Many more available.

Example only:

[image]

[Here are some examples for sale](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=471&Nav=|c:3|c:81|&Sort=0&Recs=10&SRCCODE=WEBMSNACNET&cm_mmc_o=mH4CjCQztBB!CjCECjCE) These are from $7.99 each but you can probably find cheaper.

[Here are some from $4!](http://www.nextag.com/usb-to-parallel-port-adapter/stores-html)

Comment: I'm located in India.But for a number of places I have searched for this hardware, They advertised it as, It is for use with old printers, and unlike serial port to usb converters, This doesn't have a virtual parallel port driver. So will it be able to be programmed as a parallel port ?

Comment: I have another idea. To make each switch generate a DTMF tone and transmit it through FM. I will interface an FM receiver with laptop microphone input. What is to be concerned about the latency and similar issues ?